# How to get guild by name or iterate over guild names until it matches a string?

Tags: python, discord.py

What I want is to get a guild by it's name, similar to `bot.get_guild(id)`.

e.g.

```py
get_guild_by_name(name_of_guild)
# returns discord.Guild object
```

What I've tried:

```py
tg = [g for g in bot.guilds if g.name == guildname]
if not tg:
    await interaction.response.send_message("Error: Guild not found.", ephemeral=True)
else:
    # etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code was right, but the interaction was taking too long, so I used `await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)` and then when I needed to send the message I used `await interaction.followup.send("Error: Guild not found.", ephemeral=True)`

```py
@bot.tree.commands(name="guildinfo", description="Get information about a guild the bot is in!")
@discord.app_commands.rename(guild_id = "guild-id")
async def get_guild_info(interaction: discord.Interaction, guild_id:str):
  tg = [g for g in bot.guilds if g.name == guildname]
  if not tg:
    await interaction.response.send_message("Error: Guild not found.", ephemeral=True)
    return
else:
  await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
  # however you want to grab/display the info
```